# How to use claims in WebApi with OAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

I have a WebApi2 app with OAuth authentication and I use claims to associate an user id to an access token, so in a controller I can know which user is accessing.

Q1. Is that a good approach?

Q2. Is there any way to access claims values outside the controller in a Owin WebApi app? One case is when I bind my services in my DI container and I want to pass the user id to the service

Answer (score 1):

- A1: Yes it is one of the most trending Authentication/Authorization approaches.
- A1. normally you put the current user identity in the Thread.CurrentPrincipal
  and it has a Claims member which will have your current user id

Comment: I set the CurrentPrincipal with a new ClaimPrincipal with my ClaimIdentity which contains a claim with the userId, I use Ninject as my DI container when I try to bind my service I use ToMethod for lazy instantiate the service, in the method I call Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal but I cannot find the userId in the claims list, the list is empty. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have any Async calls in your chain? It might be because you set the CurrentPrincipal in a thread and reading it from a different thread?

Comment: See this gist https://gist.github.com/marciotoshio/e54e590bb7ca9d10bbf4 it show where I create my Principal and where I try to use it

Comment: The problem is in your GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method, you are creating a new instance of ClaimsIdentity and adding the claim to that object. You should add the claim to the same object on the CurrentThread.ClaimsPrincipal

Comment: It is all okay, the problem is when I try to access the info in the NInject binds probably the Invoke method of this class http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http.Owin/HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.cs was not called if you follow this method you will see a method SetPrincipal(IPrincipal user), if I access Thread.CurrentPrincipal inside an action in any controller I can access the claims. Now I need to find a way of Ninject inject the service after this occurs. @Pinpoint in JabbR that points it to me there is an Owin channel there